# Azure chaos studio experiment deployment name failure

Tags: azure, chaos

I'm trying to crate an Azure Chaos studio experiment and deploy it to my resource group.  I set the name of the experiment as PG Cosmos Chaos, but am getting the error:

"The provided deployment name 'PG Cosmos Chaos-359c149c-cc7a-49dd-a08a-1f51550ab2c1' has these invalid characters: '  '. The name can only be a letter, digit, '-', '.' or '_'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details."

I have no other experiments deployed

Comment: Name it without spaces?

Comment: That's what it was.  Crazy it adds stuff to the end if you have spaces. Thanks!

Comment: if you put this as the answer I will accept it

Comment: Nice it helped you. As said in my answer, I cannot think of any azure resources that can be named with spaces.

Comment: Also I'd suggest you to remove the subscription ID from your question for sake of safety

Comment: thanks, that's a random guid, not the subscription id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stipulated in the error message, this azure resource cannot be created with spaces inside names.

AFAIK there are no azure ressources that accept spaces as part of their names.

> The provided deployment name 'PG Cosmos
> Chaos-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' has these **invalid
> characters: ' '**. **The name can only be a letter, digit, '-', '.' or
> '_'**. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.